Getting Column Name form results in a Select query
I am trying to name my columns from the results of a Select query using date information and variables but I am probably expecting to much from my simple query. My Table HstTotals is laid out as below:
HstTotals:
DOB        FKid   Sales
----       ----   -----
2024-05-01  600     0
2024-05-01  601     1257.89
2024-05-01  602     567.22
2024-05-02  603     238.49

What I need in the following:
FKid    2024-05-01  2024-05-02
----    ----------  ----------
601      1257.89          0
602       567.22          0
603            0     238.49

Below is the query I am using:
DECLARE @CMP VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @CMP = Convert(varchar(12),dateadd(day,-1,getdate()),23)

SELECT 
    [FKid]
    , Sum ([Sales]) AS @CMP    
FROM [Replication].[dbo].[HstTotals]
WHERE DOB BETWEEW (DATEADD(DAY, -8, GETDATE())) AND (DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()))
AND FKid > '600'
GROUP BY [FKid]

My query gives me the following error:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near '@CMP'.

In doing some research I'm not sure that I can pass a variable result along as a column name but to be honest I'm not sure if I am even starting correctly.
I would appreciate your input.

You can't... the only way you can accomplish that is with dynamic SQL and to be honest that not a recommended approach. Let you client app rename them.

Also 3-part naming of table is not best practice.

I am only trying to get the results, not intending on building a table.

Read about pivots, dynamic ones especially

@GB1975 not sure how your response relates to my comments? Nothing I said was about building a table.

@siggemannen, I think it might. Let me try it and I will respond.

@siggemannen, I believe with a little work this will do what I need. Thank you again for your help.
